# React-Native Flatlist ignoring styles

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm stuck in why the Flatlist ignores almost every style, like space-around list items and space-around header components and everything.

Here is my code:

```
renderHeader = () => {
        return (
            <Text style={styles.scheduleHeaderContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.headerNotReady}>NOT READY YET</Text>
                <Text style={styles.headerCleared}>CLEARED</Text>
            </Text>
        )
    }

    renderItemSeparator = () => <View style={{height: 10, backgroundColor: '#828282', width: 1, zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute'}}/>
...

<View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.rooms}
                style={styles.scheduleContainer}
                horizontal={false}
                numColumns={4}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderItemSeparator}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                  console.log('item', item.room);
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.elementsContainer}>
                        <Text>
                            {item.room.data.name}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
            />
        </View>
```

And here are some styles:

```
listContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    left: 14,
    right: 14,
    top: 353,
    height: 200,
},

scheduleContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', 
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '100%'
},

scheduleHeaderContainer:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
},

headerNotReady: {
    flex: 1,
},

headerCleared: {
    flex: 1
},
```

Here is the result, some of the styles not working, like flex, space-around ...

[image]

Here is the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused the problem. However, you can get a result close to the look you want from this.

https://snack.expo.io/LZGnhJwoz